# How is PaintComponent() and getpreferredsize() working when I resize the DialogWindow?

Tags: java, resize, paintcomponent

below is a working Java-Code which I do not understand.
I have outprinted the times where the programm invokes the getPreferredsize()- and paintComponent()-methods. I have found out that every time I resize the DialogWindow it calls once the getPreferredsize-method() and twice the paintcomponent-method().

Why?

```
package examples;


import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public class Bsp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new MyFrame();

    }

}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    private class MyLine extends JLabel {



        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

             Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            System.out.println("PaintComponent: "+getWidth()+" "+getHeight());
            g2d.drawLine(0, panel.getHeight()/2, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()/2);
            g2d.dispose();



        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            System.out.println("PreferredSize: "+panel.getWidth()+" "+panel.getHeight());
            return new Dimension(panel.getWidth(),panel.getHeight());
        }



    }

    public MyFrame() {

        JLabel label=new MyLine();


        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));



        panel.add(label);



        add(new JButton("A"));
        add(new JButton("B"));
        add(panel);


        pack();
        centeringWindow();
        setVisible(true);



    }


    public void borderingJPanel(JComponent panel, String jPanelname,
            String fontStyle) {

        Font font = new Font(fontStyle, Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 12);

        if (jPanelname != null) {
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory
                    .createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, Color.GRAY,
                            Color.WHITE), jPanelname,
                    TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION,
                    TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, font));
        } else if (jPanelname == null || fontStyle == null) {
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory
                    .createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, Color.GRAY,
                            Color.WHITE)));
        }

        panel.setOpaque(false);

    }

    public void centeringWindow() {
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x;
        int y;



        x = (int) (dimension.getWidth() - getWidth()) / 2;
        y = (int) (dimension.getHeight() - getHeight()) / 2;

        setLocation(x, y);
    }


    public BufferedImage getBufferedImage(){

        BufferedImage buffImage=null;

        try {
            buffImage=ImageIO.read(MyFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("examples/rightAnswerSign.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffImage;

    }

}
```

Comment: What are your expectations?

Comment: And why the concern? It is always a good to remember that you don't have control over when or if these methods get called, and so you must be sure that no program logic, no code that changes your class's state, goes in those methods.

Comment: I think that there should be one call of the getPreferred()-method (to know the actual size of the window) and one call of the paintcomponent-method() (to repaint it new) when I resize the DialogWindow

Comment: Don't do `g2d.drawLine(0, panel.getHeight() / 2, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight() / 2);` where `panel` is referencing another component in the UI, this would have component, potentially painting outside of itself. The same thing goes for the `getPreferredSize` method`